# How to know index of DataTable row just added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the DataTables jQuery plugin version 1.10.22.

I add a row to DataTable, like the following.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var data = { Id: 0, Name: 'Fred', Age: 42 };
table.row.add( data ).draw( false );
```

That works.  A new row is added to the table, and the data I provided is displayed.

But, immediately after adding the row, I would like to know the row index of that row I just added.  How do I determine that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) function returns an instance of a DataTable object containing the new row (and only the new row):

```
var newRow = table.row.add( data ).draw( false );
```

So, now you can get the assigned index from that:

```
console.log(newRow.index());
```

This is the internal DataTables index of the row - not the visual/displayed position index in the HTML table. This value does not change as the table is sorted/filtered.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always used the **index** method on the last row like this:

```
$('#example tr:last').index();
```

Here's a working demo. Just click on **"Add New Row"**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dt = $('#example').dataTable();
    dt.fnDestroy();
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    //var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ckDfqBChNK?indent=2';
    var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bQzyuEGndu?indent=2';
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      ajax: url,
      rowReorder: {
        dataSrc: 'order'
      },
      columns: [{
        data: 'order'
      }, {
        data: 'place'
      }, {
        data: 'name'
      }, {
        data: 'delete'
      }],
      
      "initComplete": function(oSettings) {
      
        $(this).on('click', "i.fa.fa-minus-square", function(e) {
          
          table.row( $(this).closest('tr') ).remove().draw();
           
        });
     
      
      }
      
    });
    
    $('#example').css('border-bottom', 'none');
    $('<div class="addRow"><button id="addRow">Add New Row</button></div>').insertAfter('#example');
    $('#addRow').on('click', function() {
        
          var rowHtml = $("#newRow").find("tr")[0].outerHTML

          table.row.add($(rowHtml)).draw();
          
          table.page( 'last' ).draw( 'page' );
          
          alert($('#example tr:last').index()); // this will return the index
        });
   
  });
```

```css
table#newRow {
  display: none
}

div.addRow {
    line-height: 45px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.0/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>order</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>country</th>
      <th>delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<table id="newRow">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Line 2
        <input type="hidden" value="2" /> </td>
      <td>DVap
        <input type="hidden" value="DVap" /> </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="22" /> </td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>  </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```